# How Many twilio numbers can I buy from single twilio account

Tags: twilio, sms-gateway, bulksms

I have an account on twilio, and I have bought a number from them. I want to buy many more numbers. I want to know that how many numbers can be bought from a single account.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is no limit on the numbers you can buy from a single account (providing we have the numbers in stock of course!). Give me a shout at philnash@twilio.com if I can help any more at all!

Comment: Thanks for the help :-) ... I will definitely ask you if I face any problem in building the Application.